# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzu;

Tags: android, google-play-services

App is crash after update my library and Error log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getNoBackupFilesDir(Landroid/content/Context;)
in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzu;                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzh.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.a.c.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.a.d.a(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.a(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.a(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.b(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.c(Unknown Source)                                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.onHandleIntent                                                                        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My Library version:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.4'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.4'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try ading `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'` and Latesest Gadle

Comment: it's not working same error.

Comment: This exception is typical for a version conflict of some kind. Code was compiled with another version of a library than is used at runtime now.

Comment: Issue is version conflict i was use quickblox sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use same version of library.
I was use quickblox sdk.
It is needed in order for using all libs with same version in my project (version of this libs in Quickblox SDK is 11.4.2 but all libs in our project must be same version)
I resolve this issue adding two more library in my `build.gradle.`

```
   compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2"
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just update your `Google Play Service` version to latest version in your `app level build.gradle file`.

```
eg. :- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.0'
```

And

Upgrade your `Firebase version` to latest and equivalent of Google Play Service Version.

```
e.g:- compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
```

In shot upgrade all your dependencies in app level build.gradle file to latest version and ensure your firebase and google play services dependencies version are same.